# AWS API Gateway Model Schema for table display on website

Tags: aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I want to display data from a API call on a Wordpress table. Most table plug-ins accept JSON results from an API call but only if it's formatted as follows

```
[
    {
      "stockId": 4,
      "description": "Powerbanks",
      "costPrice": 42,
      "salePrice": 80,
      "units": 10,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "power bank.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    },      
    {
      "stockId": 8,
      "description": "Chip",
      "costPrice": 0.5,
      "salePrice": 1.5,
      "units": 49,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "Chip.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    },      
    {
      "stockId": 9,
      "description": "Honey",
      "costPrice": 5.6,
      "salePrice": 66,
      "units": 33,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "honey.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    }
]
```

What JSON schema do I need to format the data like this? The JSON output starts/ends with [ ]

My current model schema looks like this at the moment

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Get all stock",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
        "rows": {
            "type": "array",
            "items" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "properties": {
                    "stockId": { "type": "number" },
                    "description": { "type": "string" },
                    "costPrice": { "type": "number" },
                    "salePrice": { "type": "number" },
                    "units": { "type": "number" },
                    "purchaseDate": { "type": "string" },
                    "image" : { "type" : "string" },
                    "supplierId": { "type": "number" }                            
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "stockId": 4,
      "description": "Powerbanks",
      "costPrice": 42,
      "salePrice": 80,
      "units": 10,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "power bank.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    },      
    {
      "stockId": 8,
      "description": "Chip",
      "costPrice": 0.5,
      "salePrice": 1.5,
      "units": 49,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "Chip.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    },      
    {
      "stockId": 9,
      "description": "Honey",
      "costPrice": 5.6,
      "salePrice": 66,
      "units": 33,
      "purchaseDate": "2019-09-27T00:00:00.000Z",
      "image": "honey.jpg",
      "supplierId": 0

    }       
  ]
}
```

How do I change the model schema to look like the output needed?

Comment: It looks like you just want to put the array you are given in an object where the key is `rows`. What's the problem here? Why can't you do that?

Comment: "{ "rows": [" is the issue. wpTable and other website tables require the an SQL output format. Because of the "row" element the SQL json format is not correct and the table plug-ins do not work.

Comment: I have found that the formatting of the API gateway output happens in the "Integration Response" section. I removed the row reference in the mapping and the output worked. :D So the output model schema in the API gateway doesn't affect the final formatting it seems. It only checks for validity.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to ask, what did you think JSON Schema does? It only does validation, it has nothing to do with changing the structure of JSON data. I suggest you probably want to delete this question as it doesn't make sense.